# WCF Service with custom username password authentication problem

Tags: wcf, security, ssl, https

I'm trying to secure WCF service with https and username & password. I'm using TransportWithMessageCredentials security mode and wsHttpBinding.
Right now I'm having trouble with the custom UserNamePasswordValidator, when I compare hardcoded values like this

```
if (userName == "user" && password == "pass")
    return;
```

everything works fine, but when I try to get values from database I'm getting error message

> An unsecured or incorrectly secured
>   fault was received from the other
>   party. See the inner FaultException
>   for the fault code and detail

Here's my web.config section

```
<bindings>
            <wsHttpBinding>
                <binding name="TestAuthConf" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                    <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
                    </security>
                    <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="65536" maxBytesPerRead="65536" maxStringContentLength="65536"/>
                </binding>
            </wsHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="TestAuthWCFService.TestAuthBehavior" name="TestAuthLibrary.App_Code.TestAuth">
                <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="TestAuthConf" contract="TestAuthLibrary.App_Code.ITestAuth">
                    <identity>
                         <dns value="localhost" />
                    </identity>
                </endpoint>
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="TestAuthLibrary.App_Code.ITestAuth"/>
            </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="TestAuthWCFService.TestAuthBehavior">
                    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
                    <serviceCredentials>
                        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="App_Code.CustomUserNameValidator, App_Code.CustomUserNameValidator"/>
                    </serviceCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
```

I'm using IIS7, self-generated digital certificate, and I set up SSL to accept client certificates...

Any help would be appriciated...

Comment: Probably exception in your code accessing database. Can be for example insufficient permissions to read from db. What is the inner exception? Turn on WCF tracing on the service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Comment: Inner Exception: "An error occurred when verifying security for the message", I did check permissions and everything's ok, WCF tracing is on, and I tested method accessing database, no problem there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The good news: If your custom user name / password validator is executing, the certificate has been verified, so a lot of possibilities are eliminated there.

Sounds to me like there is a bug accessing your database from within WCF's thread context. Set a breakpoint in your validator and step through.

Comment: omg... Tracer inner exception: Login failed for user... I should just add a user... :) Thanks for your help John & Ladislav... Best regards...